# Azure User delta API (beta) fields information

Tags: azure, api, microsoft-graph-api, beta, azureportal

While calling user delta API(beta version) for Azure

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http

I am getting the following fields,
"assignedPlans"
"assignedLicenses"
"licenseAssignmentStates". These fields are changing way too frequently because of which delta API keeps on getting more and more pages even for a small number of users.

https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/delta

I wanted to know what does these fields mean, however I couldn't find it in the API documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List Users operation returns a list of `user` resource type. You can find the properties of a `user` resource type here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-beta#properties.

Your read about the resources you mentioned in your question here:

**assignedPlans**: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/graph/api/resources/assignedplan?view=graph-rest-beta.

**assignedLicenses**: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/graph/api/resources/assignedlicense?view=graph-rest-beta

**licenseAssignmentStates**: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/graph/api/resources/licenseassignmentstate?view=graph-rest-beta